# Return entire contents of first document after grouping by multiple fields and sorting by date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with a structure analogous to:

```
{
    "field1" : "1_of_5_options" 
    "field2" : "1_of_5_options"
    "field3" : "1_of_5_options"

    "data1" : "value1"
    "data2" : "value2"
    "data3" : "value3"

    "created" : {
        $date : { }}
    }
}
```

I want to group the above by all combinations of field1, field2, and field3, then sort by created date in descending order and return ALL of the contents of that document as part of the set returned.

I thought I would use `$group`, followed by `$sort`, but then I get stuck on how to return all of the contents when `$first` asks that you specify a single field, when I actually want to return that entire document.

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. You can always use `"doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }` which will refer to the entire document, but of course that would mean assigning it to a single field such as `"doc"` and your whole document would be under that field. Or of course just specify "every" field you need to return with a `$first`. Nor really convinced in your question ( which lacks what you have tried, or any desired result ) that you are even on the right track for what you expect, or that your expectation is realistic. Generally when using `$group`, the "whole document" is the last thing wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Blakes.  Your suggestion to assign $$ROOT to a field will work for me.